# IntelliJ shows error highlighting for simple App in scala

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Using IntelliJ 14.1.7, I have a very simple scala app (sbt project):

```
object Startup extends App {
  println("Hello World")
}
```

I can run this in IntelliJ just fine.  However, IntelliJ shows error highlighting for "Startup" and suggesting that it needs to "implement methods" to fix it.  Here are some screenshots:

[image: IntelliJ showing error highlighting]

[image: IntelliJ mousing over error]

Can anyone please explain why this occurs and how to eliminate the error highlighting?

Comment: that version of IntelliJ is several years old, maybe try a newer one?

Comment: You're using a very old version of IntelliJ. Try updating to IntelliJ and Scala plugin 2018.1, the problem should be fixed